# Javascript Accelerometer Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, accelerometer

i want to achive an algorithm or so which will calculate the time in context with the speed of shaking a device.

More detailed:

Imagine you are shaking your mobile-device an for that it would display and loading a power status bar.

So what i want to achive is -

1. you have to start slow
2. you have to get faster constantly (not defined how much faster per/to_be_defined, just constantly)
3. there is a goal - when the status bar is fully loaded
4. so i want to meassure the time somebody needed to fill the statusbar

I have no problem in get the data of the accelerometer, but have no idea how to accomplish such a programmaticly curve calculation

i would use this for getting the data

```
window.ondevicemotion

event.accelerationGravity, with x, y, z attributes
event.accelerationIncludingGravity, with x, y, z attributes
event.rotationRate, with alpha, beta, gamma attributes
```

Any help would be much apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What data exactly does the accelerometer give you? Direction of movement? Speed of movement?

Comment: Are you looking to calculate a progress fill rate from perhaps using the rate of change of direction per second? You would have to decide on a constant, but 1% per change of direction is a start.

Comment: Calculate the difference of time differences between 1st and 2nd "shake" and 2nd and 3th "shake" , that's the constant accelerate of shakes (_kx+b_). Then define a gap and check, if shakes are within the gap (_kx+b+gap_ and _kx+b-gap_). x here  represents the time.

Comment: @Codor i updated my question so i think i have only the direction.. i couldn´t find a clear statement about that and didn´t had the time to test

Comment: @Teemu yes.. but how to update the gap frequently.. what i think now is to save the first two generated gap cycles of the user .. and then update the gap after every shake acording to the difference of the first two gaps with a threshold... am i on the right way?

Comment: @Codesleuth ah you giving me a new thought.. but there the constantly faster shaking is not considered.. right?

Comment: You don't need to update the gap. The gap is needed only to eliminate small differency in linear growth of frequency. (Without a gap players will always fail.) With those two first shakes you define the equation (_kx+b_) for the change of frequency, and the gap is just for widening this linear line a bit. I'm sorry for the poor explanation, my english math vocalbulary is really poor.

Comment: @Teemu thanks a lot, this gives me a idea how to solve it...if you could provide a real code example i accept your answer